# Python Get Request Printing specific key and value

Tags: python-requests, python-3.6, key-value

I am new to HTTP requests, and I am trying to make a simple get request using `Python` and the `Requests Library` requesting [GitHubs API](https://api.github.com/repos/git/git).

I've currently tried to implement parameters for a key and value pair

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/git/git", params= {'name':name} )
print(name)
```

Obviously this is incorrect, as I'm getting an error which says `name isn't defined` which makes perfect sense however I don't know to print specific value's from keys I want rather the printing the entire `r.json()` response.

I've just tried to use this:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/git/git")
data = r.json()

class User:
    def __init__(self, json_def):
        self.__dict__ = json.loads(json_def)

user = User(data)
print(user.size)
```

However I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking a Response object which contains [a server’s response to an HTTP request.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response). From that link, I am guessing you are trying to check for contents
from that response. So you can modify that code to this.

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/git/git")
data = json.loads(r.content)

class User:
    def __init__(self, json_def):
        self.__dict__ = data
```